# Summary report conversion

Tags: civireport

Can you convert a detailed report to a summary report, and visa versa?
I have looked everywhere and can not find out how to do it.
Many thanks
Mike

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean take a detailed report and from it create a summary report with the same criteria, there is no provision to do this. You just have to add the criteria manually to the new report.

Comment: ah thats a shame. Thanks very much.